# Calculating a location using distance and latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location

I have five Latitude and longitude and also their distance from a certain location . the question is , Is there any way I can calculate Latitude and Longitude of that certain location using this information ?

Comment: you have current location as an address ?

Comment: no as Latitude and Longitude

Comment: in vector algebra point and distance gives circel, to find a exact position you also need direction not only distance

Comment: Is there a way I can find direction to that point?

Answer (score 1):

**This might help:**

```
public class Distance {
  public static void main(String args) {
    double longitude1;// Starting Point longitude
    double latitude1; // Starting Point latitude
    double longitude2; // Destination longitude
    double latitude2;// Destination latitude

    double distance = Math.sqrt((longitude1 - longitude2) * 2 + (latitude1 + latitude2) * 2);
```

//The distance formula is based on the Euclidean distance. For more clarity visit :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance
}
}